# Firebase rule for collection start with number doesn't work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection called 2022collection but when I go to set the read access in Firestore rules it errors out, I've searched the docs and stackoverflow and am not seeing anything anywhere on how to write the rule properly to allow a collection starting with a number. I can write and read to it just fine if I'm logged in to the app, but unable to make a firestore rule to make it publicly readable. Rules for collections that start with a letter work just fine but the number errors out completely.

How do I make a Cloud Firestore rule for a document/collection that starts with a number?

Here are a couple things I've tried, clearly neither work. I would argue that there should be better documentation on this as I've failed to find anything that explains it. Happy to be proved wrong if such docs exist, I've not found them in an all my time searching [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-conditions).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with the rules that you have tried?

Comment: I updated it with a screenshot, you can see the other rules work just fine, it doesn't like the numbers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by changing my code from

```
match /2022users/{2022users} {
    allow read;
    }
```

to

```
match /2022users/{users2022} {
    allow read;
    }
```

After changing the second field I was able to save the rule and read the collection 2022users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard to read collection name and then use `matches()` to check if it starts with a number. Try the follwoing rules:

```
match /{col}/{docId} {
  allow read, write: if col.matches("^[0-9].*");
}
```

Do note that this rule will be applied for all collections since you have a wildcard.

Comment: I've tried using your code but am not quite sure if I'm doing it right, I've posted a screenshot of the way I was originally trying to write the rule if you don't mind taking a look, thank you.

Comment: @giroprotagonist so can you try using wildcards as in my answer without the var name starting with a number ?

Comment: Thanks @Dharmarj Can you please look at the second screenshot I posted at the bottom of the question. I copy pasted your suggestion and replaced the col with the collection named 2022collection. I think I am misunderstanding your instructions because I have already tried in my opinion.